# Django page, losing ChartJs rendered graph when I refresh page

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I've successfully rendered the graph in my `homepage` path, but whenever I refresh the page, I lose whatever was rendered and I'm not 100% sure why.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', chartData.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('chart/', chartData.chart, name='chart'),
    path('api/chart/data/', chartData.as_view()),
]
```

I'm not sure where the issue could be coming from and I'm fairly new to Ajax, so I believe I am missing something.

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" method="GET">
    <div class="autocomplete">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="Item" placeholder="Enter Item">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Search">
</form>

<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/'
    var dataset = []
    var labels = []
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = $('#myInput').val();
        $('#myInput').val('');
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/?Item" + item);
        $.ajax({
            url: endpoint,  
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(){
                $.ajax({                    
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                data:{
                    'item': item,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(itemName)
                    labels = data.labels
                    dataset = data.dataset
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
                    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [{
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                data: dataset,
                                fill: false,
                            }],
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            maintainAspectRatio: false,
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(error_data){
                        console.log("error")
                        console.log(error_data)
                    }               
                })  
            }
        })          
    })          
</script>

<!--JavaScript file for autofill functionality in search bar-->
<script src="static/javascript/autofill.js"></script>
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Typing 'apples' into the box returns the url `127.0.0.1:8000/?Item=apples` with the correct chart, and refreshing returns the same url but with no rendering whatsoever..?

**UPDATE 1**
Idea in comments of code, uncertain if this is a good approach?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createGraph(data, item){
        labels = data.labels
        dataset = data.dataset
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    data: dataset,
                }],
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                title: { display: true, text: item, fontColor: '#000000', fontSize: 40},                                
                }
            })
    }

    var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/'
    var dataset = []
    var labels = []
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemName = $('#myInput').val();
        $('#myInput').val('');
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/?Item=" + item);
        $.ajax({
            url: endpoint,  
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(){
                $.ajax({                    
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                data:{
                    'item': item,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    createGraph(data, item)
                    }           
                })  
            }
        })          
    })

    //checking if jquery string exists outside of function and ajax
    //if exists, then you should run the ajax again alongside the createGraph function?

    //refreshing page without any values does console.log('False')
    //refreshing page with existing jquery string does console.log('Jquery string parameter exists...')
    if(location.search){
        var item = $('#myInput').val(location.search);
        $('#myInput').val('');
        console.log('Refreshing page, jquery string value = ' + item)
        console.log('Jquery string parameter exists...')
    }
    else {
        console.log('False')
    }

</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I was able to solve the refreshing by following what @Ben said below. I checked to see if a Jquery string exists and if so, rerender the graph via the Ajax call.

```
if(location.search){
    console.log('Jquery string exists...')
    $('#myInput').val('Apples') //replace 'Apples' with var that gets 
                                //jquery string
    var item = $('#myInput').val();
    console.log('Jquery string value = ' + item)
    $('#myInput').val('');
    var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/'
    var dataset = []
    var labels = []
        $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,  
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(){
            $.ajax({                    
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                data:{
                    'item': item,
                },
                success: function(data){
                createGraph(data, item)
                }           
            })  
        }
    })
}
else{
    console.log('False')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a result because of the Submitting
`$('#submitBtn').click( [...]`, the data being downloaded triggers the creation of the graph.

I'd recommend pulling the chart creation into it's own function, then calling it both on success of the api returning data, *and* on load of the page if there are parameters available i.e. `?Item=apples`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createGraph(data) {
    console.log(itemName)
    labels = data.labels
    dataset = data.dataset
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: dataset,
                fill: false,
            }],
         },
         options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
         }
    })
};
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/'
var dataset = []
var labels = []
$('#submitBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $('#myInput').val();
    $('#myInput').val('');
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/?Item" + item);
    $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,  
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(){
            $.ajax({                    
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            data:{
                'item': item,
            },
            success: function(data){
                createGraph(data);
            [...]
            }}}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, guess my design was wrong. I'll try what you said, thanks! Although I don't think I get the 2nd part. On load of the page, so I check if parameters exist?

Comment: When you refresh, it's an empty chart (with no data), so in order for the chart to know to load anything, you need to take the parameters from the url `{"Item": "apples"}` and trigger the api call when on loading the page.

Comment: Ah, okay.. So I got the chart function pulled out, just not sure how to get the 2nd part to work. I was able to get the query string `?Item=testing%20testing` by using `console.log(locatin.search)` . So I should be checking if this exists, and if it exists (this is done outside of my button click function) then I trigger the function once again with that parameter correct?

Comment: I'm going to update my code above with what I think should work. Although I think this may require me to make another function call and ajax?

Comment: @xpeterpanx009 Yes, it looks like you're on the right track. Is it working as you intended it to now?

Comment: yes, I got it working as intended :) Only problem now is I have to account for if the user goes backwards.. I believe I have to use `window.history.back();`